# How to insert data into multiple table simultaneously in cakephp 3.6

Tags: cakephp, orm, associations, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to insert data into two table using association in cakephp but it was not workout yet.

Controller:

```
$payment =  $this->Payments->patchEntity($payment, $this->request->data, [
    'associated' => [
        'ChequeDetails'
    ]
]);
```

Model: `Payments`

```
$this->hasOne('ChequeDetails', [
    'foreignKey' => 'payment_id'
]);
```

Model: `ChequeDetails`

```
$this->belongsTo('Payments', [
    'foreignKey' => 'payment_id'
]);
```

View template:

```
echo $this->Form->input('cheque_details.cheque_no', [
    'label' => false,
    "class" => "span6 m-wrap",
    "Placeholder" => "Cheque No"
]);
```

Comment: please share your $this->request->data array.

Comment: sorry  i didn't get u

Comment: please post your $this->request->data value means write pr($this->request->data) and post it's output here.

Comment: which file u are asking

Comment: <?php   echo $this->Form->input('cheque_details.cheque_no',['label'=>false,"class"=>"span6 m-wrap","Placeholder"=>"Cheque No"]);?>

Comment: Association _property names_ for `hasOne` associations are by default singular, ie `cheque_detail` instead of `cheque_details`, see **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasone-associations** and **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#associated-form-inputs**.